# How to remove some labels from a pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a dataframe that looks like this, but larger:

```
title_of_the_novel                author          publishing_year   mentioned_cities   
0   Beasts and creatures        Bruno Ivory             1850           London 
0   Monsters                    Renata Mcniar           1866           New York 
0   At risk                     Charles Dobi            1870           New York   
0   Manuela and Ricardo         Lucas Zacci             1889           Rio de Janeiro
0   War against the machine     Angelina Trotter        1854           Paris


df_1880_1890 = pd.DataFrame({'title_of_the_novel': [Beasts and creatures, Monsters],
                   'author': [Bruno Ivory, Renata Mcniar]},
                   'publishing_year': ['1850','1866'] 
                   'mentioned_cities': ['London','New York']
```

I have successfully plotted it on a pie chart using the following code:

```
1880s_data = result[df_1880_1890].groupby(['mentioned_cities']).sum().plot(
    kind='pie', y='publishing_year', autopct='%1.1f%%', radius=12, ylabel='', shadow=True)

1880s_data.legend().remove()

1880s_data_image = 1880s_data.get_figure()
1880s_data_image.savefig("1880s_pie_chart.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

However, as my dataframe has many values, some of the labels on the pie chart represent only 0,5% or 1%. My objective is to remove all percentages below 4% from this pie chart. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: use `df.to_dict()` to make us replicate your data. Furthermore add the #pandas tag

Comment: I am very new to Python. I created this dataframe from a CSV file. I tried to do what you asked me, but I know it is not completely correct.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the output?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to add up the years and not the number of books?

Comment: I understand that a variation of +/-5 can be neglected for data that's in that yay range, and you get a sufficiently accurate estimate of the proportions, but still

Comment: I should not have tried to change the data. As I am working with another language, I thought it would have been easier to translate it. I will post a picture of the output. I think you will get the gist.

Comment: I posted a picture now, let's see if it is clearer.

Comment: It's asking for access permission

Comment: Now it should work!

Comment: It's much more cluttered are you sure you want to keep each and every category? rather than making `others` category if it's `<4%`?

Comment: That is also a good solution, GodWin! How would that work?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587997/matplotlib-pie-graph-with-all-other-categories) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69839373/group-small-values-in-a-pie-chart) for grouping small category as others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass a function to `autopct` within your call to `.plot`

```py
autopct=lambda pct: '{:1.1f}%'.format(pct) if pct > 5 else ''
```

This will return a formatted string if the percentage of a slice is `> 5` or else it will return an empty string (no label)

---

To also remove the labels, it will be easiest to dip into pure `matplotlib` for this. Using the data you provided as `df`, you can create a pie chart and access the returned text objects for the labels and the percentage labels.

All you need to do from there is iterate over them, extract the value underlying the percentage label and update as needed.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

totals_df = df.groupby(['mentioned_cities']).sum()
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(totals_df['publishing_year'], labels=totals_df.index, autopct='%1.1f%%')

threshold = 20
for label, pct_label in zip(texts, autotexts):
    pct_value = pct_label.get_text().rstrip('%')
    if float(pct_value) < threshold:
        label.set_text('')
        pct_label.set_text('')

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))
```

[image]

---

to fully remove wedges from a pie chart based on their percentage, we can add 2 lines to our previous code to iterate over the wedges at the same time when we iterate over the text labels and percentage labels. In our filtering condition we simply make the wedge itself invisible and remove its label so its not added to the legend.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

totals_df = df.groupby(['mentioned_cities']).sum()
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(totals_df['publishing_year'], labels=totals_df.index, autopct='%1.1f%%')

threshold = 20
for wedge, label, pct_label in zip(wedges, texts, autotexts):
    pct_value = pct_label.get_text().rstrip('%')
    if float(pct_value) < threshold:
        label.set_text('')       # remove text label
        pct_label.set_text('')   # remove percentage label
        wedge.set_visible(False) # remove wedge from pie
        wedge.set_label('')      # ensure wedge label does not go into legend

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))
```

[image]

---

To fix the layout of the pie, this turns back into a little bit of a data problem. We need to group all of the below threshold cities together and then remove them from the pie post-hoc.

```py
totals = df.groupby(['mentioned_cities'])['publishing_year'].sum()
proportions = totals_df / totals_df.sum()

threshold = 0.2
below_thresh_mask = proportions < threshold
plot_data = proportions[~below_thresh_mask]
plot_data.loc[''] = proportions[below_thresh_mask].sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(
    plot_data, labels=plot_data.index, autopct='%1.1f%%'
)

for w, alab in zip(wedges, autotexts):
    if w.get_label() == '':
        w.set_visible(False)
        alab.set_visible(False)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))
```

[image]

---

Though it may be better to simply group those cities into an "other" category.

```py
totals = df.groupby(['mentioned_cities'])['publishing_year'].sum()
proportions = totals_df / totals_df.sum()

threshold = 0.2
below_thresh_mask = proportions < threshold
plot_data = proportions[~below_thresh_mask]
plot_data.loc['other'] = proportions[below_thresh_mask].sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(
    plot_data, labels=plot_data.index, autopct='%1.1f%%'
)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, but can I remove the labels as well? The code you provided made the percentages below 5% desapear, but the are labels still there. Can we remove them as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am really sorry. I may have not well explained what I want. On your pie chart, London is still there. I want it to be removed. You see, if the mentioned city is cited less than 3% of the time, I should not be there. It is irrelevant.

Comment: The data you supplied did not have those values. If you use the code I provided, you should be able to change the `threshold` variable from `20` to `3` and you should get your desired result.

I had to change the threshold to 20% (instead of 3%) to make some labels disappear from the sample of data you provided :)

Comment: Unless I'm still misunderstanding. You want London to not appear at all as a wedge from the chart? Or do you not want London to be apart of the legend?

Comment: Yeah, to not appear at all, that's it Cameron!

Comment: Updated my answer to remove entire wedges, let me know if that is what you're looking for!

Comment: Cameron, you are fantastic! Is there a way to maintain the pie form, though, because it did work, but now we have got an odd form. Maybe I am asking too much.

Comment: If It can't be done, just tell me I will mark your answer as the best one. Indeed, it is!

Comment: Anything can be done in `matplotlib`, just added in a way to group the cities into an 'other' category, and how you can go about removing it from the pie as well.

Comment: I got this error here Cameron: ValueError: x must be 1D. When trying your second option, which is great!

Comment: Sounds like you have a `DataFrame` with a single column instead of a `Series`. Make sure you select the `['publishing_year']` from your `DataFrame` at some point prior to passing it into the `.pie` method. I did this as part of my `.groupby` operation: `.groupby([...])['publishing_year'].sum()`